# Challenge : Return flat array of 'codes', for ALL objects with property a = true

Tags: javascript

An array of objects,
Each Object has three properties;
– code, a unique ID.
– A, ( true || false ) || Object.
– B, ( true || false ) || Object
The a and b properties can either be a boolean value or have a another full object contained.
Challenge : Return flat array of 'codes', for ALL objects with property a = true.

```js
// INPUT
let testArrIn = [
  {
    code: 'fef151b1da',
    a: true,
    b: false
  },
  {
    code: '20d94b8eed',
    a: false,
    b: {
      code: '68b6251d7e',
      a: false,
      b: true
    }
  }, 
  {
    code: 'f8ba2c86e7',
    a: {
      code: '059fddc166',
      a: {
        code: 'bb4e57b0c9',
        a: true,
        b: false
      },
      b: false
    },
    b: false
  }, 
  {
    code: '282e8f8fec',
    a: false,
    b: false
  }, 
  {
    code: 'b36148f916',
    a: true,
    b: {
      code: 'cc481394e3',
      a: {
        code: '83b7ef55c4',
        a: true,
        b: false
      },
      b: false
    }
  }
];

// EXPECTED OUTPUT
let testArrOut = ['fef151b1da', 'bb4e57b0c9', 'b36148f916', '83b7ef55c4'];
```

Comment: Hi there @Rohisha Ramauthar, you would make it easier to answer your question if it's more readable. The easier it is to read, the more help you'll get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const testArrIn = [ { code: 'fef151b1da', a: true, b : false }, { code : '20d94b8eed', a : false, b : { code : '68b6251d7e', a : false, b : true } }, { code : 'f8ba2c86e7', a : { code : '059fddc166', a : { code : 'bb4e57b0c9', a : true, b : false }, b : false }, b : false }, { code : '282e8f8fec', a : false, b : false }, { code : 'b36148f916', a : true, b : { code : 'cc481394e3', a : { code : '83b7ef55c4', a : true, b : false }, b : false } } ];

const check = (acc, {code, a, b}) => {
  if (typeof a === 'boolean' && a) {
    acc.push(code);
  }

  if (typeof a === 'object') {
    check(acc, a);
  }

  if (typeof b === 'object') {
    check(acc, b);
  }

  return acc;
};

const result = testArrIn.reduce(check, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```js
var a =  [{
    code: 'fef151b1da',
    a: true,
    b: false
 }, {
    code: '20d94b8eed',
    a: false,
    b: {
        code: '68b6251d7e',
        a: false,
        b: true
    }
 }, {
    code: 'f8ba2c86e7',
    a: {
        code: '059fddc166',
        a: {
            code: 'bb4e57b0c9',
            a: true,
            b: false
        },
        b: false
    },
    b: false
 }, {
    code: '282e8f8fec',
    a: false,
    b: false
 }, {
    code: 'b36148f916',
    a: true,
    b: {
        code: 'cc481394e3',
        a: {
            code: '83b7ef55c4',
            a: true,
            b: false
        },
        b: false
    }
 }]
 let out = []
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if(a[i]['a']){
    out.push(a[i]['code'])
  }
}

console.log(out)
```

Comment: This produces an output of `["fef151b1da", "f8ba2c86e7", "b36148f916"]`, which is not OP's expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I first flatten each object in the array into an array of objects using some recursive logic. Then I flatten the array of arrays into one big array. Then I filter by a being true. Then I map by code.

Hopefully this helps! I personally do not enjoy nested objects and would suggest using references or foreign keys instead.

```js
let testArrIn = [ 
  { 
    code : 'fef151b1da', 
    a : true, 
    b : false 
  }, 
  { 
    code : '20d94b8eed', 
    a : false, 
    b : { 
      code : '68b6251d7e', 
      a : false, 
      b : true 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    code : 'f8ba2c86e7', 
    a : { 
      code : '059fddc166', 
      a : { 
        code : 'bb4e57b0c9', 
        a : true, 
        b : false 
      }, 
      b : false 
    }, 
    b : false 
  }, 
  { 
    code : '282e8f8fec', 
    a : false, 
    b : false 
  }, 
  { 
    code : 'b36148f916', 
    a : true, 
    b : { 
      code : 'cc481394e3', 
      a : { 
        code : '83b7ef55c4', 
        a : true, 
        b: false 
      },
      b : false 
    } 
  } 
];

function flatMapCodeObjsArr(codeObjArr) {
  return codeObjArr
    .map(e => flatMapCodeObj(e))
    .flat();
}

function flatMapCodeObj(codeObj, objArr = []) {
  objArr.push(codeObj);
  const values = Object.values(codeObj);
  const objs = values.filter(o => typeof o == "object");
  for (const obj of objs) {
    flatMapCodeObj(obj, objArr);
  }
  return objArr;
}

const processed = flatMapCodeObjsArr(testArrIn);
console.log(
  processed
    .filter(({a}) => a == true)
    .map(({code}) => code)
)
let testArrOut = [ 'fef151b1da', 'bb4e57b0c9', 'b36148f916', '83b7ef55c4' ];

console.log(testArrOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of objects,
Each Object has three properties;
– code, a unique ID.
– A, ( true || false ) || Object.
– B, ( true || false ) || Object
The a and b properties can either be a boolean value or have a another full object contained.
Challenge : Return flat array of 'codes', for ALL objects with property a = true.

// INPUT let testArrIn = [ { code : 'fef151b1da', a : true, b : false }, { code : '20d94b8eed', a : false, b : { code : '68b6251d7e', a : false, b : true } }, { code : 'f8ba2c86e7', a : { code : '059fddc166', a : { code : 'bb4e57b0c9', a : true, b : false }, b : false }, b : false }, { code : '282e8f8fec', a : false, b : false }, { code : 'b36148f916', a : true, b : { code : 'cc481394e3', a : { code : '83b7ef55c4', a : true, b : false }, b : false } } ];

// EXPECTED OUTPUT let testArrOut = [ 'fef151b1da', 'bb4e57b0c9', 'b36148f916', '83b7ef55c4'

Answer (score 0):

For the coding answer, @Alexandr Shulaev's answer was spot on. I thought I'd just elaborate more on the problem and the solution:

The Problem:
You were given an Array of objects. Each `Object` has an identity (The Code), as well as 2 components (A and B). Each component can either be a `boolean` value, or another `Object`. Thus, you were essentially given an Array of nested objects. You were asked to traverse through this array, and identify all the objects with a `boolean` A-component of value `true`.

The Solution:
*Firstly*, it helps to identify that the input data given resembles that of a **Binary Tree** (a tree where each node has a maximum of 2 branches):
[Binary Tree Representation of Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sytq4.png)
An `Object` is represented as a Branch Node (has branches), identified by its code.
A `boolean` is represented as an End Node (no branches), identified by its value.

*Second* is to find a way to traverse through this tree (or array of trees). The two main ways of traversal are though iteration (`for` loops, `while` loops) and recursion:

**Iteration** is good for things which are balanced and even (think tables and grids), where you'd want to travel row by row, left to right, or in a similar orderly fashion. To iterate through a tree, however, is far more difficult (impossible?), especially when dealing with *unbalanced* trees (trees with one side longer than the other).

**Recursion** on the other hand does well when it comes to trees. Its method of traversal follows the tree branches and tries to reach the End Node in one direction before reaching the other direction: [Traversal Direction using Recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyY9U.png) (mind my drawing).

Recursion is when a function calls itself continuously until some stopping condition is met. In this case, it is when an End Node (`boolean`) is seen. In @Alexandr Shulaev's code, the first thing his recursive function does is the processing bit:

```js
if (typeof a === 'boolean' && a) {
  acc.push(code);
}
```

Basically, if you're currently on a node where the A-component is a Boolean of value `true`, then add the current node's code to the output array.

Next, he deals with the traversal (the recursive bit):

```js
if (typeof a === 'object') {
  check(acc, a);
}
if (typeof b === 'object') {
  check(acc, b);
}
```

For each component, he does recursion based on a condition. Recursion MUST have a stopping condition, otherwise you end up with... What's the name of this site again? :P
In this case, the stopping conditions are essentially the negatives of the above, i.e. when `typeof a !== 'object'` for component A, and similar for B.

The last bit of processing is to return the output array to the calling method. Alexandr chose to pass the output array `acc` in and out of the function, whereas I would have made it a global variable, leaving out the extra parameter and return value. Both result in the same: at each node, the node's code gets pushed to the array (if the condition is met), and the final array has codes populated in the order of traversal.